# Is there a simple way to get unique items from DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to grab all unique items from a DropDownList. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always iteration:

```
Dim uniqueItems As New ListItemCollection()
For Each myItem As ListItem In listitems
    If Not unique.Contains(myItem) Then
        unique.Add(myItem)
    End If
Next
```

This is probably not the simplest answer in terms of runtime or code, but it is the simplest concept (for me, at least).

EDIT: Code for mat1t's solution

```
Dim uniqueValues As IEnumerable(Of ListItem) = DropDownList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Distinct() 
DropDownList1.DataSource = uniqueValues
DropDownList1.DataBind()
```

Comment: that assumes a Equals compare on each object.

Comment: Looking at his other questions, I think this is what he means.  He is not looking for the most programmatically correct way, he wants it to just work.

Comment: hey matthew i am going to use your solution. help me hook this up. how do we declare "unique"??

Answer (score 4):

If you're allowed to use LINQ in this code (from .net 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008 onwards) look at the Distinct extension method.

```
dropdown.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Distinct()
```

It will do all of the hard work of determining whether an item is unique behind the scenes

Comment: @alex - yes you can.  I think this is actually your best option.

Comment: @alex - as long as you are working in .NET 3.5 or higher, this is definitely your best shot.

Comment: i have this

DropDownList1.DataSource = dv
        DropDownList1.DataBind()

DropDownList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Distinct()


but it did not work

Comment: Are you trying to only populate the listbox with unique values? If so then you want to apply the distinct filter when you set the datasource (or before)

Comment: DropDownList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Distinct()
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dv
        DropDownList1.DataBind()

didnt work

Comment: try DropDownList1.DataSource = dv.Distinct()
What is dv?

Comment: Distinct returns an object. Try this: Dim uniqueValues AS IEnumerable (OF ListItem) = DropDownList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Distinct()

Comment: Dim dv As DataView = ds.Tables("Country").DefaultView
        'or we can use:  
        'DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;  

        'Now sort the DataView vy column name "Name"  
        dv.Sort = "Name"

Comment: Dim uniqueValues As IEnumerable(Of ListItem) = DropDownList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Distinct()

        DropDownList1.DataSource = dv
        DropDownList1.DataBind() did nto work

Comment: @mat1t, it appears your solution produces an IEnumerable, which cannot bind to a DropDownList.  Which sucks, cause this was very elegant.

Comment: There's another extension method on IEnumerable called ToArray (or ToList if you prefer) that will then convert it into something you can bind to a DropDownList

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Dim uniqueSet As New HashSet(Of ListItem)(dropdown.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)())
```

This is assuming of course that you have .NET 3.5 at your disposal.  The [`HashSet(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) type is a strongly-typed collection of unique items.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys i have tried all three methods described above but I keep getting returned a empty list or a list full of duplicates, i'm using a LINQ data source, so I cant alter the select statement, tried 'DISTINCT' but no luck....

Sets up the initial values for the drop down menu, works and shows lot of values

```
Dim context As WeldsDataContext = New WeldsDataContext()
Dim query = From BIDNumber In context.Fab_Missing_NDTs Select BIDNumber

DropDownList1.DataSource = query.ToList()
DropDownList1.DataBind()
```

'Should remove all none-distinct values?

```
Dim uniqueSet As New HashSet(Of ListItem)(DropDownList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)())
DropDownList1.DataSource = uniqueSet
DropDownList1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add them all to a hashtable to build the unique items.